# Dom Security Error 18 when readpixels on webgl

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, webgl

When I’m trying to do picking on webgl, I use the framebuffer and read the pixel color to do this. And it throw the (SECURITY_ERR : Dom Exception 18) while the function gl.readpixels run.

[image: screenshot]
http://imageshack.us/f/94/readpxielerror.jpg/

I don’t know how to solve this problem.

So help me please !!!

Comment: Is that image located on localhost? Such errors are usually related to  cross domain issues.

Answer (score 2):

Host the image in the same host were your page is served, webgl marks the canvas as tainted when you use a cross-domain resource for rendering. Had the same problem and that solved it.

Edit:

To expand a little bit, current WebGL implementations do this as a mechanism to not allow malign pages to exploit drivers to take control over a user workstation.  Remember that you pass an array for the readPixels call and this could be used for a buffer overflow attack rendering WebGL as a potential security risk.

2nd Edit:

There's currently work in progress to support even better cross-origin images in canvas and webgl, you can check it [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html)